# Highlight line number of folded lines

Tags: folding, highlight, line-numbers

I want to have uniform highlighting of line numbers (provided by the *LineNr* and *CursorLineNr* hl-groups) but the line numbers of folded lines don't obey a particular group (as far as I know), but obey the highlighting of the *Folded* group.

As you can see in the image of my *~/.vimrc* file, the line-numbers of unfolded lines are bold with yellow foreground; while the line-numbers of folded lines are regular with white foreground (the same configuration of the rest of the folded line).

[image: Example of irregular line-number color of folded lines]

So, how can I make the folded-lines' number become equal of the rest of the LineNr column?

Comment: This is not possible. The whole line belongs to the `Folded` highlight group.

Comment: The closest you'll get is `:hi! link linenr folded` :-)